# Derive distribution from normal distribution with unknown mean

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I'm having trouble with this question since mean is unknown.  If the mean is centered around 0, I think I can solve.

Let  be with  ∼(, 1). Define a set of new random variables X such that

```
X={1 if >0, 0 if <=0
```

Question is:
Derive the distribution of X and show that it depends on .

Answer (score 0):

$X_i$ takes only two values $0$ and $1$. So finding the distribution of $X_i$ is just finding the probabilities that this variable takes the values $0$ and $1$.

$P(X_i=1)=P(Z_i >0)=\frac  1 {\sqrt {2\pi}}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-(x-\mu)^{2}/2} dx =\frac  1 {\sqrt {2\pi}}\int_{-\mu}^{\infty} e^{-y^{2}/2} dy=1-\Phi (-\mu)$ and $P(X_i=0)=1-P(X_i=1)=\Phi (-\mu)$ where $\Phi$ is the standard normal distribution function.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Are you familiar with normal distribution? Do you know the density of normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $1$?

Comment: Yes, but the −μ does not make sense to me.

Comment: @c123prob I just made the substitution $y=x-\mu$ in the integral.